# Spring Integration - Control retry logic in http outboundAdapter

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-http, spring-integration-amqp

I configured a route in Spring Integration 5.4.4 that read from an AMQP queue and write to an http outbound adapter.
I'm not able to control retries when, for example, I programmatically declare a wrong http hostname for the http outbound adapter (Cause java.net.UnknownHostException).

This seems to generate an infinite retry (message not acked on RabbitMQ container), even if I configured the RetryTemplate logic in the amqpInboundAdapter.

My goal should be: **requeue the message for N times in case http outbound adapter is in error, discard the message otherwise and don't requeue again**.

Code here:

Spring Integration route

```
public IntegrationFlow route(AmqpInboundChannelAdapterSMLCSpec amqpInboundChannelAdapterSMLCSpec) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(amqpInboundChannelAdapterSMLCSpec)
                .filter(validJsonFilter())
                .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("X-Insert-Key",utboundHttpConfig.outboundHttpToken))
                .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("Content-Encoding", "gzip"))
                .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("Content-Type", "application/json"))
                .handle(Http.outboundChannelAdapter(outboundHttpConfig.outboundHttpUrl)                         .mappedRequestHeaders("X-Insert-Key")
                        .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                )
                .get();
    }
```

AmqpInboundChannelAdapterSMLCSpec

```
public AmqpInboundChannelAdapterSMLCSpec gatewayEventInboundAmqpAdapter(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {

        RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();

        exceptionClassifierRetryPolicy.setPolicyMap(exceptionPolicy);
        retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(new ExponentialBackOffPolicy());
        retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(new SimpleRetryPolicy(1));
        retryTemplate.setThrowLastExceptionOnExhausted(true);

        return Amqp
                .inboundAdapter(connectionFactory, rabbitConfig.inboundQueue())
                .configureContainer(c -> c
                        .concurrentConsumers(3)
                        .maxConcurrentConsumers(5)
                        .receiveTimeout(2000)
                        .alwaysRequeueWithTxManagerRollback(false)
                )
                .retryTemplate(retryTemplate);
    }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

> requeue the message for N times in case http outbound adapter is in error, discard the message otherwise and don't requeue again.

When you use a retry on the AMQP MessageListenerContainer, there is on requeue: the retry is done in the memory without round trips to the broker.

Anyway what you do so far is OK. Only what you are missing is a `RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer` to be configured for that `Amqp.inboundAdapter()` to decide what to do with an AMQP message when all the retry attempts are exhausted.

Unfortunately the direct `MessageRecoverer` configuration for channel adapter has been added since version `5.5`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.5.0-M3/reference/html/whats-new.html#x5.5-amqp.

For the current version it has to be done via `recoveryCallback(RecoveryCallback<?> recoveryCallback)` option and respective delegation:

```
   .recoveryCallback(context -> {
        org.springframework.amqp.core.Message messageToReject =
            (org.springframework.amqp.core.Message) RetrySynchronizationManager.getContext()
                    .getAttribute(AmqpMessageHeaderErrorMessageStrategy.AMQP_RAW_MESSAGE);
        throw new ListenerExecutionFailedException("Retry Policy Exhausted",
                new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException(context.getLastThrowable()), messageToReject);
    }))
```